# Aren't comparison questions welcome on SO?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

[What questions can be asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says:

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Suppose I have a query like whether to use "A" or "B" for a use case, are such questions welcome?

Comment: Those could easily become _opinion based_.

Comment: Yes but they could but they would clear out lots of doubts a person may have.

Comment: Well, no matter [opinion based questions are off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: So every ["vs" question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vs.) or ["should I use" question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=should+I+use) would be off topic?

Comment: 'they would clear out lots of doubts a person may have' no, that is not a lock.  It may add to the doubts.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes it may add to doubts which he may ask the answerer and hence making it a good Q & A to refer if anyone else gets the same doubt.

Answer (score 9):

The [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) provides a pretty good explanation on why subjective questions (such as "should I use A or B for problem X") are generally not welcome at Stack Overflow.

An exception is usually made when there's a wide consensus on the subject within the relevant community (e.g., "I need to write a C program that sums two numbers. Should I start with writing my own compiler?"), but even that's not guaranteed.

Comment: If you [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=should+I+use+for), you may find most question here as per your definition is not welcome on SO.

Comment: @AniMenon yes, but note that many of those are years old; times change, and SO's focus has narrowed.

Comment: @AniMenon Note that the top five relevant questions there are more than four years old, and would probably be offtopic by *today's* standards. After that point, the search term becomes way too wide. The sixth most relevant question in this search is "Which mime type should I use for mp3?" There's nothing opinion-based here - there's an actual problem that can be answered with "use type X" or "use type A for browser B", not with "I like using XYZ because...".

Comment: @Mureinik Pls read the question again, I have specified comparison for "a use case", which means its specific.